# how to disable mat-radio-buttons after an option is selected

Tags: angular, typescript

In my **[quiz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app)**, I need to disable the mat-radio-buttons after an option has been selected. I have `[disabled]="alreadyAnswered"` on my mat-radio-buttons in my template and have `alreadyAnswered = false;` in my TS file declaration. When an option is selected, `this.alreadyAnswered = true;` is set in the setSelected(i) function. Once an option is selected, all of the other options should be disabled and grayed out. Please can you help me with this. Thank you.

in SingleAnswerComponent template:

```
<div *ngIf="!multipleAnswer">
  <div class="options" *ngFor="let option of currentQuestion.options; index as i">
    <mat-radio-button (change)="setSelected(i)" [disabled]="alreadyAnswered" [class]="option.className">
      <span i18n>{{ i + 1 }}. {{ option.text }}</span>

      <ng-container>
        <i class="material-icons feedback-icon" *ngIf="option.correct && isCorrectAnswerSelected">done</i>
        <i class="material-icons feedback-icon" *ngIf="!option.correct">clear</i>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-radio-button>
```

Comment: What is the current result? What happens exactly?

Comment: Right now all the options in the single answer are clickable and when I click on an option, all the other options are still clickable, would like it so that it disables the other options from clicking (grayed out).

Comment: I see. We'll need to see more code then. Is that radio button part of a component? Are all buttons inside the same component? Otherwise you'll have to use a service to communicate to other components that a button was clicked (unless you already have this?).

Comment: Yes the mat-radio-button is part of the SingleAnswerComponent (see my edit above) and all radio buttons are in the same component.

Answer (score 1):

You could/should wrap your `mat-radio-button` in [mat-radio-group](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview#radio-groups) to make a group of radio boxes, then you will have ability to "disable" the whole group, which will prevent select any other options, as soon as one has been selected via simple Boolean flag bind to the mat-radio-group.

Please check an example below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbhewk-pw5jfs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-overview-example.html

Comment: I wrapped it in mat-radio-group and added onChange function but it still doesn't seem to disable the other options. Please can you see my code on Stackblitz. Thanks.

Comment: so it looks like in your example all of quizzes setup in a way where they have multiple choices, which means checkboxes, not a radio button, so it's hard for me to test.

Comment: All of the quizzes have single-answer questions so it shouldn't be that difficult to test.

Comment: when i inspect your app in browser, i can clearly see that only `codelab-question-multiple-answer` component has been rendered, which underneath renders `mat-checkbox`

Comment: another thing that you should wrap mat-radio-group BEFORE your repeater, not after
so, all the radio buttons per question single question should be wrapped into one mat-radio-group

Comment: I wrapped mat-radio-group before the repeater, but still not able to get it to disable.

Comment: yes, I can see that. Now you need to figure out why your app renders codelab-question-multiple-answer component instead of codelab-question-single-answer, that's why you are not able to verify results...

Comment: I noticed that I had .mat-checkbox-layout inside my single-answer's CSS, but that still doesn't answer why it isn't rendering as single-answer/mat-radio-buttons.